# What should be the return type of this function?

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, return-type

I am having this function which will return list of cities based on the state.Here is the function.

```
public IList<string> GetCity(int index)
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
         var city = db.mem_cities.Where(c => c.state_id.Equals(index)).Select(c => c.city_name).ToList();
         return city;
    }
}
```

Now I call this function from my code behind like this.

```
var city = CustomerBLL.GetCity(index);
```

`CustomerBLL` is my `class`

Now I want to fill my DropDownList with the cities returned.
So I do something like this.

```
ddlCity.DataSource = city;
ddlCity.DataBind();
```

This works fine.Earlier I tried using `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var c in city)
{
    ddlCity.Items.Add(c.city);
}
```

But it gave an error

> string does not contain a definition for string

So my question is suppose if I wanted to iterate through the List what should I return from the function.

Can someone point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Don't you want to name it `GetCities()`?

Comment: Change `ddlCity.Items.Add(c.city);` to `ddlCity.Items.Add(c);`?

Comment: @HarveyKwok I did that , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return not a city names (City.Name) but cities themselves:

```
public IList<City> GetCities(int stateId)
{
     return db.Cities.Where(c => c.StateId == stateId)
                     .ToList();
}

var cities = GetCities(x);
foreach (var c in cities)
{
    ddlCities.Items.Add(c.CityName);
}

var newCity = new City { CityName = "Home", StateId = x };
cities.Add(newCity);
```

Comment: If I return what you suggest then I can use c.city right?Thanks.

Comment: @freebird: Yes, you can add a city to a list of cities directly.

Comment: @freebird: You need to change dropdown binding options to bind to the CityName object property.

Comment: It is working now as my object is mem_city and not city so IList<mem_city> worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: @freebird: I would recommend to name type in more readable manner.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are returning a list of string you can simple do `Add(c)` instead of `Add(c.City)`:

```
foreach(var c in city)
{
     ddlCity.Items.Add(c);
}
```

Or you can modify your function to return IQueryable

```
    public IQueryable<City> GetCity(int index)
    {
        using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var city = db.mem_cities.Where(c => c.state_id.Equals(index));
            return city;
        }
    }
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach(var c in city)
{
     ddlCity.Items.Add(c.City);
}
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake , ya I just need to do that , thanks for pointing out , also both the methods of filling the dropdownlist seem to be working , which is a good way.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetCity` method returns a `List<string>`. Therefore when you code

```
foreach(var c in city)
{
  ddlCity.Items.Add(c.city);
}
```

Each c is a string. So you should be doing ddlCity.Items.Add(c).

Comment: Thanks a lot , I realized that now.